# Given a Python class, how can I inspect and find the place in my code where it is defined?

Tags: python

I'm building a debugging tool.

IPython lets me do stuff like

```
MyCls??
```

And it will show me the source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sys.modules[MyCls.__module__].__file__
```

or

```
inspect.getsourcefile(MyCls)
```

There are more [`__xxx__` attributes](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) on various objects you might find useful.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a pretty good overview of many of Python's meta-info capabilities:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pyint.html

Answer (score 2):

The [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect) module has everything you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see the source, [inspect.getsource](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) is a very direct way to do that; for more advanced uses (getting the source *file*, line numbers, etc), see other functions in `inspect` documented at the same URL just before `getsource`.  Note that each such function will raise an exception if source is not available, so make sure to be within a `try`/`except` block when you call it, and handle the exception as appropriate for your case. (Also, as I might hope goes without saying, you do need to `import inspect` in your modules in which you want to call `inspect` functionality).